# How to set up a query

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, pivot

I have 2 tables, one of users and the other of posts with the following structure:

```
id  post    user_id created_at
1   text1   1       2022/01/01
2   text2   2       2022/01/01
3   text3   1       2022/01/01
4   text4   1       2022/01/02
5   text5   2       2022/01/02

id  name
1   user1
2   user2
3   user3
```

I currently have the following query:

```
SELECT
  posts.created_at,
  users.name,
  COUNT(posts.id) AS posts_
FROM posts
  INNER JOIN users
    ON posts.user_id = users.id
GROUP BY posts.created_at,
         users.name
```

With this I have the number of posts per day of each user. But I want to go far and I want that on the days that there are posts if a user has 0 that I also show it and I don't know how to do it.

How could I do it?

Thanks

Comment: How is this data being used? It might be easier to fill in the gaps via PHP after querying the data.

Comment: the data is loaded in an array to later display it in a calendar with fullcalendar

Comment: As you iterate over the calendar days on the view, just display the data if it exists for that day, otherwise leave the day blank.

Comment: As a general note, when filtering/grouping try to use indexed columns whenever possible. Eg: `users.id` rather than `users.name` in the `GROUP BY` clause. The DB will be able to leverage the index to operate more efficiently rather than having to scan all the fields.

Comment: Is that really the date format in your database, or just how you present it to us here? If it is the format you have, we can assume you're not storing them in a proper date-column (which uses the format `Y-m-d`). If so, you should fix that.

Comment: thanks @M.Eriksson. In the database they are in the correct format, only that I put it here as I show it on the web.

Comment: @msmahon Yes, that's what I do now, but even if user doesn't have any posts, I'm interested in showing the user who doesn't have anything and putting it in a different color.